# Eloquent - ManyToMany with additional relation on pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many

I'm looking for how to do something like this with Eloquent :

[image]

A game has one or many ratings, and these ratings has one or many descriptions. 
These ratings have not always the same descriptions, it depends which games, so it's why I added the relationship between RatingGame and RatingGameDescription and not directly between Rating and RatingGameDescription.

For the moment, in my app, I have this models :

Game

```php
    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function ratings(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Rating::class, 'fhi_ratings_games', 'game_id', 'rating_id');
    }
```

Rating:

```php
    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function games(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class);
    }
```

RatingGame

```php
    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function ratingGameDescriptions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RatingGameDescription::class, 'rating_game_id', 'id');
    }
```

When I get a game, I can see his ratings, no problem with this, but I don't know how to add the 'ratingGameDescriptions' relation on my pivot.

Do you have an idea to do this ?

Thank you =)

Comment: What code are you using to fetch the results you desire?

Comment: I tried to do like this for example on the first element : ```$game->ratings->first()->pivot->ratingGameDescriptions```